# What is the purpose of throwing all caught exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I'm going through our code for our core programs to refactor and I encountered this weird try/catch block

```java
try {
    //Do some socket and network stuff
} catch (NoRouteToHostException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    throw e;
} catch (IOException e) {

    throw e;
} finally {
    //Does some counting stuff over here
}
```

Now I can't understand why on earth someone would do something like this, the people who wrote this code have left the company, but were indeed very skilled.

Is there a purpose to this try/catch block? Would it not be better to just throw these exceptions and do the finally things from where the method is called?

Comment: None at all. Remove the catches. Try/finally is totally fine.

Comment: What version of java does this use?  In modern versions of java (post 7...  Maybe...), `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` will cover all of the cases above and still retain information about what types can be thrown for the enclosing scope.

Comment: Do the catch clauses just throw the exceptions they catch, or is there some additional logic you omitted from the catch blocks?

Comment: it's very well possible that before the code was supposed to perform different actions for each exception, or it was expected that they would have to be handled differently, but 'has to be decided by business'.
As you've shown it, there is no reason. Maybe he thought it was easier to read which Exceptions can be expected here.

Comment: I have seen such code where we used to send the exception data to Splunk logs in the catch block, then re-throw (propagate) the exception.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's no longer the case in modern java versions (as alluded to in my comment).  I've added a similar catch-all block before so that I can log and then quickly rethrow, and the type information is still maintained for the method doing this.

Comment: @user2478398 I live and learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either they didn't know they could write `try-finally` without `catch` or it's a legacy piece and it formerly performed something different for each `catch` block.

Otherwise, it makes no sense and it's identical to

```
try {
    // Do some socket and network stuff
} finally {
    // Does some counting stuff over here
}
```

Even skilled people tend to make mistakes, particularly when a deadline approaches.

Answer (score 2):

If you do *literally nothing* with the exception before you rethrow it, there is no point in catching it. Remove the catch block for that particular exception.

`try` doesn't need any `catch` blocks, provided there is a `finally`.

Note that `catch (SomeException e) {}` *is* doing something with the exception: it is swallowing it (which is likely not advisable anyway). As such, you cannot remove this without changing semantics.

The only exception (no pun intended) is if you don't want  to catch a particular subclass of an otherwise-caught exception. For example:

```
try {
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  throw e;
} catch (IOException e) {
  // Do something.
}
```

If you were to remove the catch/rethrow of `FileNotFoundException`, it would change the semantics because it would be handled by the more-general `IOException`. As written, a `FNFE` will "leap frog" the catch block for `IOE`.

(This is only very occasionally useful).

Answer (score 0):

If you throw every exception you catch, you will end up with an unhandled exception and your application will crash. At some point in your code, you will have to decide how you will deal with the error. If you are writing a GUI application this may be at the GUI layer, where you display an error message to your user. However, throwing all exceptions caught is no different to simply marking your method with `throws IOException, ...`.

Also, since Java 7, you can use **try-with-resources**, for example:

```
try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()) {
    socket.getInputStream()  // whatever
} catch (IOException e) {
    doSomething(e);
}
```

Note that you can still omit the catch block and simply pass the exception up to the enclosing scope.